# Powershell: How to get the folder name under the path and truncate the first 4 digits of the name, that is, truncate the year

Tags: powershell

Currently I want to get all the folder names under the path and intercept their years for comparison with the current year.
[image]
You can successfully obtain all file names under this path using PowerShell, but it is not clear how to substring these folders through the results.

Comment: Use SubString method : $folder = 'c:\temp\Others'

$folderYearNames = Get-ChildItem -Path $folder | foreach { $_.Name.Substring(0,4) }

Comment: You have provided a description of the task but the code of your own attempt at solving the problem is missing. The chances of getting a helpful answer are usually higher if you provide a code sample (at least for "successfully obtain all file names under this path").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways to do it, depending on what you need.

For example, if you want a list of all the directories where their name starts with a specific year you could use `Get-ChildItem -Directory -Filter "$date*"` which matches all the directory with their name starting with `$date`
Note that while `-Filter` is the most efficient method to... well, FILTER results from Get-ChildItem, it is limited into supporting only `*` and `?` wildcards.
You might want to use `Get-ChildItem -Directory | Where-Object -Property Name` with its various flags to perform more complex filters

More generally speaking of strings and substring, you can use use `-like` and `-match` or even `.indexOf`(it's a method of the `[string]` class) to look for a substring inside a string.

If you specifically need a "truncate", then `.substring`(another `[string]` method) is what you want to use

Comment: I tried it and it works, thanks